# Obter div bem acima na hierarquia

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho essa hierarquia em HTML

```
<div class="footer">
            <div class="send_show" style="height: 754px;"></div>
            <div class="forms_sends">
               <span class="sends">
                  <div class="icon-container">
                            <button class="send">ENVIAR</button>

                   </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

e desejo que quando for clicado no botão de classe `.send`, uma mensagem seja exibida em `send_show`. Só que existem várias hierarquias dessas na página, ou seja, deve ser pega a `send_show` do respectivo botão.

Estou usando jQuery para realizar isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando parents() para subir para a div "pai" depois desce com children() para a div "filha" que você deseja. Assim você pode ter essa estrutura em vários lugares pois só a que está junta ao pai vai ser afetada.

```
$(".send").on('click', function() {
    $(this)
     .parents(".footer") //Sobe para o pai do evento click
     .children(".send_show") //Desce para a filha
     .html("Div mais próxima");
});
```

Espero que seja isso.

Comment: Outra forma é usar o `.parents`  para chegar em `.forms_sends` e usar o `.prev('.send_show')`